# How to set up multiple proxies in Vue.js with different ports and same paths

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, proxy, axios

So, I'm trying to figure out how to proxy to different servers with different ports and same paths.

xxx.vue:

```
  axios.get('/actuator/health/')
    .then(response => this.status = response.data.status)
    .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
```

here is my config.vue.js :

```
module.exports = {
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    '^/actuator/': {
      target: 'http://localhost:59400/',
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure:false,
      pathRewrite: {'^/actuator': '/actuator/'},
      logLevel: 'debug'
    }
  }
}
```

}

and I want to get data from port 8787 with the same path :

http://localhost:8787/actuator/health

how can I do it? if I can't change the path.

Comment: so you want to get the data only from the 8787? if so then just replace 59400 target port.

Comment: No, from both 8787 and 59400

Comment: You cant get 2 responses from 2 different places on the same request, because then how would you use the data? maybe try and explain why you need to do this and we can find a better solution

Comment: In every port there is a component (java service), and I want to dislay the name of the component, the status and the version of each component in my interface.

Comment: I have 2 other methods for the name and the version too

Comment: so you need to make a different call for each service separately, so you can use the correct data for each service. you can use `Promise.all()` to send the request at the same time without waiting for each one to resolve and then call the other. also this proxy only works for your dev environment so if you build this project for production it has no effect at all.